# Elliptical light on polarizing beam splitter

Tags: optics, polarization

I've been trying to gain an understanding what would happen to an elliptically polarized light (including the special case of circular polarization) when incident on a polarizing beam splitter cube (MacNeille stack design) - namely, how would the state of polarization change for the reflected\transmitted light.

Comment: I'm surprised that after 10 hours there is no answer yet, so maybe I just don't understand the difficulty. The light gets decomposed into the eigenpolarizations of the beamsplitter. Vertically polarized light is reflected while horizontally polarized light is transmitted. Is that what you ask?

Comment: That would be the answer for an unpolarized light, but is it also the case for elliptical light?

Comment: Yes, elliptically polarized light is a linear combination of horizontally and vertically polarized light, just as unpolarized light. The difference is that in unpolarized light there is no fixed phase relation between the two components.

Comment: And wat would be the proportion of the decomposition? The orientation of the electric field is constantly changing with respect to the S\P direction of the cube.

Comment: Also, shouldn't there be any ellipsometric effects on the reflected light?

Comment: Since Maxwell's equations are linear you can just see it this way: If you look at only the vertical component of the electric field you find that it oscillates sinusoidally, and if you look at the horizontal component you find that it also oscillates sinusoidally (with a different phase). So essentially the elliptically polarized wave is just the two waves superimposed. This is what I meant by decomposition.